# Windows schtasks Not Able to Create Log File

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 to create `schtasks`. Here is the command to create the task:

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 5 /tn ClearCache /tr "powershell.exe -NoProfile - NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File full\path\clear_cache.ps1 >> full\path\clear_cache.log 2>&1"
```

For testing purpose, my clear_cache.ps1 only does `echo "123"`. When I manually run

```
powershell.exe -NoProfile - NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File full\path\clear_cache.ps1 >> full\path\clear_cache.log 2>&1
```

it works perfectly fine by creating a log file with `echo "123"` in it, but when I put it in schtasks, it doesn't create the log file. In schtasks log, it just says task completed successfully with a return code 0.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. Instead of calling powershell.exe to direct output to log file. I wrote the directing output to log file part inside my `clear_cache.ps1` script directly. It worked.